# Is there a way to connect a .net-core app in docker container to docker-kubernates instance?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, .net-core

I am working on an app where all our code is in .NET-core API. When I create the container it contains my app plus the NuGet (custom package). This app is dependent on consul which is deployed on Kubernetes on the same system. When I run the code in debug mode it works fine but when I run it with docker support it gives me an error when it hits the code where the consul is referred.

I have tried accessing it with different port settings (pod and service). It is still giving me error.

Comment: Make sure that Consul is running and reachable from your Docker container. You can try running a command inside the container to ping Consul to see if it is reachable.

Comment: I wouldn't try to mix container systems.  Kubernetes can be especially ill-suited for local development, since it's much more designed as a cluster environment.  If you just need a Consul instance, can you launch it in Docker without Kubernetes?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Since, it is working in your debug mode. Because you might be pointing to its address by something like `localhost:port`. But, when running in container, the same `localhost` is not the same. Now localhost points to container. You need to configure networking while running this container. Try with host networking